# Handling exceptions in Scala object constructors

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to use Lift JPA and when I reference Model, it calls the super constructor I'm getting an exception:

```
object Model extends LocalEMF("LiftPersistenceUnit") with RequestVarEM
```

The problem is that the exception is hidden behind this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class...
```

So, my question is: what is the best way to log/handle exceptions in this case?

Alternatively, can anyone recommend another pattern to use Lift JPA? The way Model has been code is the recommended way, but it's not very user-friendly IMO. The idea is to have a singleton entity manager factory which is accessible via a request variable.sc

Answer (score 4):

I can think of the only way to execute something prior to `LocalEMF`'s constructor:

```
class Model(val init: Unit = println("Hai")) 
  extends LocalEMF("LiftPersistenceUnit") with RequestVarEM
```

Maybe you could proxy a call to `LocalEMF("LiftPersistenceUnit")`, and add appropriate logging on exceptions, using some extraordinary trick.

**EDIT**

I found it:

```
class LocalEMF(haha: String) { val e = throw new RuntimeException }
trait RequestVarEM

class Model(val init: Unit = println("Hai")) extends { val e = 
  try new LocalEMF("LiftPersistenceUnit") catch {
    case t: Throwable => println("Catched: " + t); throw t
  } 
} with RequestVarEM
```

Comment: Side note: the curly braces inside `try ... catch` are unnecessary.

Comment: This solution produces a compiler error: only type definitions and concrete field definitions allowed in early object initialization section

Comment: The idea was in a catching class initialization exception, in "descendant"-s early initialization section. Updated the code, but as I remember, it worked fine ?! Rather strange