# Declaring @throws annotation on a class

Tags: class, scala, exception

Regard to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209753/scala-problems-in-default-constructor-with-try-catch-block), can I declare a class as:

```
class XmlDemo extnds ICurrenciesModel @throws(classOf[NullPointerException])
```

Meaning that inherits from another class written in Java and annotation that it can throw an Exception

It does not work for me and it's related to the problem earlier.

Comment: Please format you code using four blank spaces. This will allow proper syntax highlighting (to do that click on the `{}` icon after selecting the block of code).

Comment: Please, edit you question to include the compiler error message.

Comment: Side note: classes can't throw exceptions, only their methods or constructors. Moreover, `NullPointerException` is a Java remnant, it should not be used in well written Scala code.

Comment: @PéterTörök I would say throwing any other exception than IllegalArgumentException or it analog in *constructor* is really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Scala REPL:

```
trait ICurrenciesModel
class XmlDemo extends ICurrenciesModel @throws(classOf[NullPointerException])
```

You mispelled "extends", also all your code blocks, in this question and in previous one, are ending with rather strange "`"

This question could help: Handling exceptions in Scala object constructors [Handling exceptions in Scala object constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114491/handling-exceptions-in-scala-object-constructors/14115105#14115105)

Comment: the ending `\`` is the fault of editors, they changed inline to multi-line code blocks but didn't delete the end marker.